# Cursor adapter in android

Tags: android, android-adapter

I can't able to set the `visibility` for row layout in `bindview` method of `CursorAdapter` class. (I'm getting empty space)

**code**

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    // Gets handles to individual view resources
    final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();           
    Contact contact = new ContactDatabase(context).getContact(cursor, "_id");
    String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("follower"));
    Log.d("Body", "" + body);
    if (body == null) {
        holder.rowlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE)
    } else {
        holder.rowlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.text1.setText(contact .getName()); 
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: show your full code of bindView()

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to hide any row item.
best practice is to implement filterable and avoid that data to bind in the adapter.

as like...

```
class ContactListAdapter extends CursorAdapter implements Filterable {
        public ContactListAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
            super(context, c);
            mContent = context.getContentResolver();
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            final TextView view = (TextView) inflater.inflate(
                    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, parent, false);
            view.setText(cursor.getString(COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME));
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            ((TextView) view).setText(cursor.getString(COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME));
        }

        @Override
        public String convertToString(Cursor cursor) {
            return cursor.getString(COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME);
        }

        @Override
        public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterQueryProvider filter = getFilterQueryProvider();
            if (filter != null) {
                return filter.runQuery(constraint);
            }

            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                    Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                    Uri.encode(constraint.toString()));
            return mContent.query(uri, CONTACT_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
        }

        private ContentResolver mContent;
    }

    public static final String[] CONTACT_PROJECTION = new String[] {
        Contacts._ID,
        Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
    };

    private static final int COLUMN_DISPLAY_NAME = 1;
}
```

you can filter out your data in implemented method.

```
@Override
public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint) {
      FilterQueryProvider filter = getFilterQueryProvider();
      if (filter != null) {
          return filter.runQuery(constraint);
      }

      Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
            Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
            Uri.encode(constraint.toString()));
      return mContent.query(uri, CONTACT_PROJECTION, null, null, null);
}
```

Happy Coding...